# Insert figure directive in table in docutils

Tags: restructuredtext, docutils

I am trying to make a table with some figure inside. I am asking if there is a possibility to do it in Docutils or in some other markup languages. I was trying this kind of table :

`+-----------------+--------+--------------------------------------------+
| Prova           | Prova  | Cella Molto lunga                          |
+-----------------+--------+--------------------------------------------+
| Visualizzazione | Figura | .. figure:: ~/Dropbox/rst/Pics/plantum.png |
|                 |        |   :alt: Prova                              |
+-----------------+--------+--------------------------------------------+`

The result is [image: Table]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible. You did it correctly. The only issue may be that your image path may be incorrect (thus the broken image icon).